# How to pass variable in request body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to pass one variable in request body.But whole body needs to go as a string.

for example :

```
var xyz = "abc";
var requestBody = '{"name":"xyz"}';
```

How can I pass the variable value in request body.Whole request body needs to go as a string.Complete string has one variable.

Comment: this should be pretty basic concatenation -> `var requestBody = '{"name":"' + xyz + '"}';`

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ name: xyz });`

Comment: @adeneo Thanks.It solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or instead of building a JSON string manually, make an object and call `JSON.stringify()` on it:

```
var requestBody = JSON.stringify({ name: xyz });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

```
var requestBody = `{"name":"${xyz}"}`;
```